# Add records to List

Tags: c#

Here is my public class:

```
public class CharactersOnline
{
    public int connectionId;
    public int characterId;
    public string characterName;
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public List<CharactersOnline> charactersOnline = new List<CharactersOnline>();
chraractersOnline[chraractersOnline.Count + 1].connectionId = 1;
chraractersOnline[chraractersOnline.Count + 1].characterId = 2;
chraractersOnline[chraractersOnline.Count + 1].characterName = "Test";
```

Where is my mistake? Why i'm not able to add these records to the list ?

Comment: Because you need to initialize the object. Initializing the list does not initialize the different indexes. Also you should specify what the problem with the above code (null reference exception)

Comment: Use `charactersOnline.Add(new CharactersOnline(...))`.

Comment: Use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for public member names and use properties instead of feilds.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek can you please make a complete example as an answer ?

Comment: It looks like you just need to read the [List<T> Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (not tested):

```
public List<CharactersOnline> charactersOnline = new List<CharactersOnline>();

var characterOnline = new CharactersOnline{connectionId = 1, characterId = 2, characterName = "test"}; //creates a new instance of your object

charactersOnline.Add(characterOnline); //adds the single new instance of your object to the list
```